# Migrated from commons-lang-2.6 to commons-lang3.12.0, facing error: NestableException

Tags: apache-commons

Recently migrated from commons-lang-2.6 to commons-lang3.12.0, getting below error: `org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException`

How to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue as apache has taken support from Nestableexception in commons-lang3

moreover your java version might be older. They have used java 5 in lowest version of commons-lang3, and in version: commons-lang3.12.0.jar, they have used java 8+

So, if you want to update commons-lang, need to upgrade jdk also. Thats the only solution.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html
(see under nested exception)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi